# Angular query search for all array objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I am new to Angular and I need your help writing a custom filter where I can search through all array objects and get my matching results that would ignore  period(.) and commas(,).  For example, if I type "ashton," I should get "stash" and "ashton marton".  But I am at a loss and need some advice.  Here's what I have so far.

In my angularSearch.html I have this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>x
    <title></title>
</head>
<body ng-app="storeSearch">
<div ng-controller="searchController">
    <label>Search: </label>
    <input type="text" class="search" ng-model="searchString" placeholder="Search"/>
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="p in products | searchFilter: searchString">
        <td>{{p.product_code}}</td>
        <td>{{p.subname}}</td>
        <td>{{p.description}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
<script src="app/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My app.js is shown below.

```
var app = angular.module("storeSearch", []);

app.controller("searchController", ["$scope", function($scope){
    $scope.products = [
        {
            product_title: "A-2368",           
            description:"Asthon Martin",
            sub_name:"2000 model ashton martin"
        },
        {
            product_title:"S-2310",           
            description:"Stash of money",
            sub_name:"Rolls Royce"
        },
        {
            product_title:"h-2369",           
            description:"Honda Civic 2003",
            sub_name:"Marton Ashton, Honda Series"
        }
    ];

}]);

app.filter('searchFilter', function(){
    return function(arr, searchString){
        if(!searchString){
            return arr;
        }
        var result = [];
        searchString = searchString.toLowerCase();
        angular.forEach(arr, function(products){
            if(products.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1){
                result.push(products);
            }
        });
        return result;
    };
});
```

Comment: What is the problem? What is your expected output if you type `ashton`?

Comment: @ShaohaoLin yeah, but "ashton" should be pulled from product_title, description and sub_name.  I want the search to look in all places and not just "description".

Answer (score 3):

One thing you need to change in order to have your filter working, is this:

```
products.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString)
```

`value` is not a property of your array, so try changing that to:

```
products.description.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString)
```

This will compare the property `description`. Now you can implement the details. Your version is causing an error in the console, because `products.value` is undefined and you try to call `toLowerCase()` on undefined. My suggestion will fix that.

**Update:**

If you like to run over all your properties, you can try to extend your loop like this:

```
angular.forEach(arr, function(products) {
    for (var property in products) {
        if (products.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            if (products[property].toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1) {
                result.push(products);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**Update 2**

According to your comment you want to modify the comparison of the properties a little, I guess you would also like to choose the properties that you actually want to compare to.

```
app.filter('searchFilter', function() {
    return function(arr, searchString) {
        var result, property, activePropertyList;

        activePropertyList = ['description', 'product_title', 'sub_name'];
        result = [];

        function isPartofSearchString(propVal, searchString) {
            propVal = propVal.replace(/\W+/g, '').toLowerCase();

            return propVal.indexOf(searchString) !== -1;
        }

        if (!searchString) {
            return arr;
        }

        searchString = searchString.toLowerCase();

        angular.forEach(arr, function(products) {
            for (property in activePropertyList) {
                if (isPartofSearchString(products[property], searchString)) {
                    result.push(products);
                    break;
                }
            }
        });

        return result;
    };
});
```

Function `isPartofSearchString()` substitues your critera (this makes things a little cleaner). `activePropertyList[]` defines the names of all properties, that you want to compare with. Since you have a `||` expression, it is sufficient, if one property matches your criteria -> hence the `break` to make it more efficient.

I know, there is still room for improvement here: e.g. you could move parts of your filter to the controller (the comparison function and the definition of the active properties), but I wanted to keep your code in the filter for this example.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, but I don't just want to search for the description.  I want to search for all array values including the product_title and sub_name.  If i have 10 values in my array, I want to search for all values within my array.  How would I write this?

Comment: So then you'll use `(products.descipription.toLowerCase... !== -1) || (products.product_title.toLowerCase... !== -1) || (products.sub_name.toLowerCase... !== -1)`

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones thanks for the feedback but if I had 20+ objects I don't want to list all of them in that way.  I actually have 15 objects for my real code project so I wanted  a better way to code without listing all the objects keys with || sign.

Comment: You can try to loop over your properties. I updated by answer to suggest an example.

Comment: Good answer! Thanks @GuidoKitzing!

Comment: Sorry @GuidoKitzing, but the code you sent after I modified my code didn’t really output what I wanted.  This code below is working but I need to make it into a few pieces of code and clean up.  Any advice on how to make it more efficient? Thanks again!

Comment: angular.forEach(arr, function(products){
             if(products.description.replace(/\W+/g,'').toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1 ||
              products.product_title.replace(/\W+/g,'').toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1 ||
              products.sub_name.replace(/\W+/g,'').toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1 ||
products.description.replace(/\W+/g,'').toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1){
                 result.push(products);
             }
         });
         return result;

Comment: I updated my answer. BTW: You are double-checking the 'description'-property.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.filter('searchFilter', function(){
    return function(arr, searchString){
        var stripped = searchString.replace(',', '').replace('.', '').toLowerCase();
        return arr.filter(function(member) {
            return member.description.indexOf(stripped) > -1;
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the comment.  But I need to search within all values of my array object and not just "description".  How do I make it so that it searches for any matching search input?